# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\order\instagramapi.php on line 28

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

Why I'm having the above error in the following code, is the syntax is not ok,I'm working on authorization with Instagram.

```
 public function getAccessTokeAndUserDetails($code){
    $postFields = array(

        'client_id' => $this->clientId,
        'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
        'grant_type' => "authorization_code",
        'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectURI,
        'code' => $code
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, option:CURLOPT_URL,value:"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");//line 28
    curl_setopt($ch, option:CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, value:1);
    curl_setopt($ch, option:CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, value:0);
    curl_setopt($ch, option:CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, value:0);
    curl_setopt($ch, option:CURLOPT_POST, value:1);
    curl_setopt($ch, option:CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response,assoc:true);

}
```

Comment: `value:`, `option:`, etc - where did you find this syntax? It almost looks like you've managed to copy some hints from an IDE. You just need to provide the actual values for the parameters, not the argument names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function getAccessTokeAndUserDetails($code){
        $postFields = array(

            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => "authorization_code",
            'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectURI,
            'code' => $code
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");//line 28
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response,assoc:true);

}
```

*option* and *value* no need to be there. It's like placeholders in the documentation. Documentation refers to the position. It's a function so you need to know which values to pass to this function in order to work and most important in which order.